# Typescript. Correctly typing function parameter that depends on property in the same object literal

Tags: typescript

I have types where one depends on another:

```ts
type source = string | number;
type derivative<T extends source> = T extends string ? string[] : number[];
```

I can use them in function arguments and get correct inference:

[image]

Now I want to use them in interface:

```
interface Test<T extends source> {
    src: T;
    handler: (dvr: derivative<T>) => void;
}
```

Again I can use it as function input and get right types:

[image]

But if I need to pass several tasks, typescript can't infer right type:

[image]

Is it possible to fix this? Presumably by changing `handleTestArr` function definition.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20source%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0D%0Atype%20derivative%3CT%20extends%20source%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20string%20%3F%20string%5B%5D%20%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handle%3CT%20extends%20source%3E(src%3A%20T%2C%20handler%3A%20(dvr%3A%20derivative%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ahandle(''%2C%20x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%0D%0Ahandle(1%2C%20x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Test%3CT%20extends%20source%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20src%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20handler%3A%20(dvr%3A%20derivative%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleTest%3CT%20extends%20source%3E(t%3A%20Test%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AhandleTest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20src%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20handler%3A%20x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleTestArr(ts%3A%20Test%3Csource%3E%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AhandleTestArr(%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20src%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20handler%3A%20x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20src%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20handler%3A%20x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%5D))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately elegant solution like tuple types will not work here, typescript will jump to `number|string` instead of inferring based on `src`.

The simplest solution is use a tuple parameter (with optional members) and several type parameters for each member of the tuple. This is not ideal (at least we don't have to define an overload for each number of parameters as we did in older versions of Tyepscript before 3.0)

```
function handleTestArr<
    T extends source,
    T1 extends source,
    T2 extends source,
    T3 extends source,
    T4 extends source,
    T5 extends source,
    T6 extends source,>(ts: [Test<T>, Test<T1>?, Test<T2>?, Test<T3>?, Test<T4>?, Test<T5>?, Test<T6>?])   
function handleTestArr(ts: Test<source>[]) {
}
handleTestArr([
    {
        src: 1,
        handler: x => {}, // x is number[]
    },{
        src: '1',
        handler: x => {}, // x is string[]
    },

])
```

Comment: Can you point me to any issue that highlight similar problem in typescript repository?